# Finding the values of k for an equation which is a tangent to a curve

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

I have been faced with the following question:

> Find the values of $k$ for which $y = kx - 2$ is a tangent to the curve
>   $y = x^2 - 8x + 7$

I managed to figure this out by treating them as simultaneous equations and then calculating the discriminant so that k either has the value $-14$ or $-2$ however I was wondering if there was another possible method to answer this perhaps by way of differentiation.

**EDIT**

And using differentiation how is it possible to get the answer that k is either $-14$ or $-2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The tangent at $(a,b)$ is $y=(2a-8)(x-a)+b$.

> Since $(a,b)$ is a point on the parabola, we have $b=a^2-8a+7$. Hence the tangent equation is $y=(2a-8)x-a^2+7$, i.e. $k=2a-8$ and $a^2-7=2$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that k is 2a-8 as that is from differentiating the initial equation however how do you get to the answer from there that k is either −14 or −2?

Comment: $a^2-7=2$ implies $a=\pm 3$. Then $k=2a-8$.

Comment: Got it, thank you. One last thing, how do you know that $a^2−7=2$?

Comment: Every line (inparticular, tangent) may have only one equation of the form $y=kx+b$. If you have $y=(2a-8)x-a^2+7$ and $y=kx-2$ then ...?

Comment: Therefore $b = -a^2 + 7$ and $-2 = b$, therefore $-2 = -a^2 + 7$ which is the same as $2 = a^2 - 7$ or as you put it $a^2 - 7 = 2$, thank you very much

Comment: Then $a^2 = 9$ which means $a = \pm 3$ and then substituting back into $k = 2a - 8$ where $a = 3$ would make $k = 6 - 8 = 2$ or where $a = -2$, $k = -4 - 8 = -14$. It all makes sense now, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> Find the values of $k$ for which $y = kx - 2$ is a tangent to the curve
>   $y = x^2 - 8x + 7$

- Where do the equations intersect? Solve for $kx - 2 = x^2 - 8x + 7$.
- Where is the slope of the line $y = kx - 2$ $\Big($ Slope = $ \frac{d}{dx}(kx - 2) = k\Big)\;$ equal to $\;\frac{d}{dx}(x^2 - 8x + 7) = 2x - 8\;$?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm good with the first part and understand how you have calculated the slope of the two equations by differentiating but how would you figure out where the slopes become equal, so when $k = 2x - 8$?

Comment: @amWhy: needs another TU! +1

Answer (score 1):

HINT

For the graphs $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ to be tangent at $x=a$ you need

$$f(a)=g(a)\text{ and }g'(a)=f'(a).$$