# A curve has the parametric equations $x=2t^2$ and $y=4t$. What is the value(s) of $k$ such that $y=x+k$ is a tangent to the curve?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curves, parametric, tangent-line

A curve has the parametric equations $x=2t^2$ and $y=4t$. Find the value(s) of $k$ such that $y=x+k$ is a tangent to the curve.

I get that you need to use differentiation to do this and I've tried doing these before with questions such as this one: [Finding the values of k for an equation which is a tangent to a curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482127/finding-the-values-of-k-for-an-equation-which-is-a-tangent-to-a-curve) but I'm not exactly sure how to figure this one out. Please help ASAP and please be **detailed** in the working out so I can understand :)

***Thank you!***

Comment: You may want to start by telling us where you're having difficulties. Do you know parametric differentiation - using chain rule? And when a line is a tangent to a curve at a certain point, what does that mean? Two things: that point is common to both curve and line and also that the slope of the tangent equals to the derivative of the curve function evaluated at that point. Can you put all this together?

Comment: Eliminating the parameter you have the parabola $y^2=8x$ so you deduce only one line is tangent. It is with $k=2$.

Comment: What’s the hurry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you know parametric differentiation using chain rule.

The requirement $y=x+k$ is tangent to the curve essentially means the slope, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, of both curves are equal. The slope of the line is $1$, and slope of curve at $(2t^2,4t)$ is:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = \fbox{Try it yourself} =^{\textrm{Want to equal to}} 1$$

From that you get the value of $t$, and thus the point $(2t^2,4t)$, which you can then substitute into the line equation $y=x+k$ to get the value of $k$.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to pass from the parametric form, to linear form. In particular, we can substitute $t=\frac{y}{4}$, so:
$$x=\frac{y^2}{8}$$
This is a parabola, with vertex in $O(0,0)$ and so the tangent lines are given by:
$$x=\frac{(x+k)^2}{8}$$
with $\Delta=0$, or:
$$4(k-4)^2-4k^2=0\leftrightarrow 4k^2-32k+64-4k^2=0\leftrightarrow 32k=64\leftrightarrow k=2$$
The only line is so:
$$y=x+2$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're probably having difficulty with the differentiation so let me start you off with a hint.

Using chain rule (this is the basis of parametric differentiation), $\frac {dy} {dx} = \frac {\frac{dy} {dt}} {\frac {dx} {dt}} $.

First start by working that out in terms of the parameter $t$.

Equate it to the slope of the tangent ($1$). What is $t$ at this point?

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the tangent slope is 1, which leads to

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = \frac1t=1\implies t=1$$

Then, the tangent point is $(2t^2,4t)=(2, 4)$. Plug into $y=x+k$ to obtain $k=2$.